# deployJava.js stopped working on chrome v.42

Tags: google-chrome, deployjava

I am trying to use the deployJava.js script from Oracle to check the installed java version. It works fine on FireFox and IE10 but fails in the latest version of Chrome (v. 42).

Has anyone encounter that error?

This is the code I'm using with the latest version of deployJava.js :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="deployJava.js">
    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    var isJava6 = deployJava.versionCheck("1.6.0+");

    if (isJava6) {
            alert('java 6 or greater was found');
    } else {
            alert('no java 6 or greater was found');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

On version 42 chrome comes by default with NPAPI disabled which disable NPRuntime Script Plug-in Library for Java(TM).

Once this plugin-in is disabled, deployJava.js is unable to fetch the current installed java version and always redirect you to java site to download the latest java version.

A workaround for that (suppose to work till v. 45) is to enable NPAPI by doing the following:

1. On chrome address bar write: chrome://flags/#enable-npapi.
2. Look for "Enable NPAPI Mac, Windows".
3. Enable it.
4. Close chrome and kill all chrome tasks from tasks manager.
5. Re-open chrome.

Comment: Looks like they pulled out the "Enable NPAPI" option by at least v. 48.  Do you know if they replaced it with any other workarounds?